# the x should be =28.24778761 but i get 28

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++

In this program i try two categorize two resistors based on their values
but at the end i cant print out correctly the x but only the part before ,
for example i tried r1=0 r2=50 r3=100 r4=60 V=9 n=4 1st value=55 2nd=56 3rd=52 4th=57 x should be 56*57/(56+57)=28.24778761 but i only get 28 why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    float V, TOTAL1, TOTAL2, y;
    int r1, r2, r3, r4, i;
    cout << "Give r1: "; // Ask for resistors.
    cin >> r1;
    cout << "Give r2: ";
    cin >> r2;
    cout << "Give r3: ";
    cin >> r3;
    cout << "Give r4: ";
    cin >> r4;
    cout << "Give voltage: ";
    cin >> V;
    cout << "Give number of resistors: ";
    cin >> n;
    int a, b; // Ccount the number on its category.
    int m;
    m = 0;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    y = 0;
    TOTAL2 = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        y = TOTAL2 + y; // Calculate the as they are in series
        float value;
        m = m + 1;
        cout << "\n Give resistance: ";
        cin >> value;
        if((value >= r1) && (value >= r2) && (value <= r3) && (value <= r4))
        {
            if(m % 2>0)
            {
                cout << "It belongs to the first";
                a = a + 1;
                TOTAL1 = value + TOTAL1; // If they are in the first category they are connected in series
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "It belongs to the second";
                b = b + 1;
                TOTAL2 = 1 / value;
            }
        }
        else if((value >= r1) && (value <= r2)){
            cout << "It belongs to the first";
            a = a + 1;
            TOTAL1 = value + TOTAL1;
        }
        else if((value >= r3) && (value <= r4)) {
            cout << "It belongs to the second";
            b = b + 1;
            TOTAL2 = 1 / value + 1 / TOTAL2;
        }
    }
    long double x;
    x = 1 / y;
    cout << "\n The first category has: " << a;
    cout << "\n The second category has: " << b;
    cout << "\n The total resistance of the first category is: " << TOTAL1;
    cout << "\n The total resistance of the second category is: " << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you refactored your code to have the inputs you gave so that if somebody wanted to test an answer they only needed to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `y` is only updated at the top of the loop, so the last update is lost. So `y` contains 1/28 (the first value), and when you take its reciprocal, you get 28 exactly.